# Create a top navigation bar based on pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, navigation

I was given publishing environment access to SharePoint Office 365. I am looking to create a top navigation bar that looks similar to the attached picture. Any directions is much appreciated!

[image]

Under site settings -> Look & Feel -> Navigation option, there is nothing available to me (it seems Top Links section is available to non-publishers only)

Thanks for the time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For normal team sites the top link bar or global navigation can be managed through the "Top Link Bar" link under "Look and Feel" section in the site settings page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But I don't have that (based on my read-up - they are saying it may not be available to publisher accounts)

Here is what I have

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Dingo
The link below may not be at your level of permissions, yet, but if you have thus far been delegated permissions enough to access the ‘Site Settings’ pages, rest assured- you are almost there - permissions-wise.

The site you are dealing with is likely using a “Communications” or “Teams” site template.

Familiarize yourself with this documentation about Modern SharePoint navigation:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/organize-your-sharepoint-sites-with-megamenu-navigation-and-new/ba-p/328068

Once you know the path you want to go, ask the admin for a temporarily higher permission level, preferably ‘Full Access’ or ‘Contibute’ OOTB permission levels.

It appears that your admin may have custom permission levels set on the site that you are attempting to customize.
Read the first reference below: you clearly need the ‘Site Owner’ role permissions on this Modern SharePoint site.

References:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-site-governance-permission-and-sharing-for-site-owners-95e83c3d-e1b0-4aae-9d08-e94dcaa4942e

Additional, perhaps helpful references:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions

Teams vs SharePoint Permissions for Goups connected Teams sites:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/permission-model-differences